# How to sum within a group of values and then take the difference from another group?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pivot, difference

Let say I have this simplified dataframe with three variables:

```
ID    sample  test_result
P1    Normal           9
P1    Normal           18
P2    Normal           7
P2    Normal           16
P3    Normal           2
P3    Normal           11
P1     Tumor           6
P1     Tumor           15
P2     Tumor           5
P2     Tumor           15
P3     Tumor           3
P3     Tumor           12
```

I want to know how to sum the `test_result` values for each identical `ID` in each sample type (i.e. `Normal`, `Tumor`).  Then I want to then take the difference between the summed normal and tumor `test_result` values.

I have tried using groupby on sample column and then use the diff() method on test_result column but that did not work.  I guess I need to know how to do apply the .sum() first, but not sure how.

Here is what I have tried:

```
df.groupby('sample')['test_result'].diff()
```

The output I am expecting is like:

```
ID   test_result
P1             6 # (the sum of P1 Normal = 27) - (the sum of P1 Tumor = 21)  
P2             3
P3            -2
```

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','sample'])['test_result'].sum().unstack()
```

Or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='sample', values='test_result', aggfunc='sum')
```

and then subtract columns:

```
df['new'] = df['Normal'] - df['Tumor']
print (df)
sample  Normal  Tumor  new
ID                        
P1          27     21    6
P2          23     20    3
P3          13     15   -2
```